# MongoDB: PLAIN method not suported

Tags: mongodb, hibernate

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to deploy my war artifact. My app is using hibernate ogm and it's trying to build persistence context when it's deployed. The message I'm getting is:

> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datatore provider Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000071: Unable to start datatore provider Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001214: Unable to connect to MongoDB instance: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='living', source='lvdb', password=, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'Unsupported mechanism PLAIN' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { \"supportedMechanisms\" : [\"MONGODB-CR\", \"MONGODB-X509\", \"SCRAM-SHA-1\"], \"ok\" : 0.0, \"errmsg\" : \"Unsupported mechanism PLAIN\", \"code\" : 2, \"codeName\" : \"BadValue\" }}}] Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='living', source='lvdb', password=, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'Unsupported mechanism PLAIN' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { \"supportedMechanisms\" : [\"MONGODB-CR\", \"MONGODB-X509\", \"SCRAM-SHA-1\"], \"ok\" : 0.0, \"errmsg\" : \"Unsupported mechanism PLAIN\", \"code\" : 2, \"codeName\" : \"BadValue\" }}}]"}}

What do I need to do in order to use the other mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to specificy the property `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_mechanism` (see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#mongodb_specific_configuration_properties)).

Which is the authentication mechanism you'd want to use? We may not support it yet, but if you let us know about your preference, we can try and look into making it work quickly.

Comment: As far I've been able to figure out about that is that there're three kind of authentication mechanisms on mongodb (`user:password`, `using a X509 certificate`, and using a third `kerberos`). I must to say that we're using a single `user:password`, so I'm able to use  mechanism `PLAIN`, `SCRAM-SHA1` or `CR`. I'm able to authenticate using `db.auth()` on mongodb shell, nevertheless, I don't quite understand what's failing when I'm trying to authenticate a user using the mongo driver or hibernate ogm.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB, default supported mechanism is 'SCRAM-SHA-1'. So, while connecting, you need to specify this mechanism. I saw the same error when connecting to MongoDB through spring-data. While I didn't make any special configuration for mongo, first and obvious option for me to try was PLAIN mechanism for authentication. Finally, resolved it using SCRAM-SHA-1.
For Spring-data, code looked something like this:

```
MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(mongoUser, mongoDB, mongoPass.toCharArray());
```

Hope this helps.